# Visual Studio 15.8.5 suddenly not displaying errors in real time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Developing in C# and something changed - not sure what. Now errors do not show in real time in the error window. I have "Build + Intellisense" selected. If I type garbage in the code it does not recognize it until I build the app manually. When I switched to an old VB.net app it worked fine.

I tried updating in an effort to resolve the issue but the update fails.

Comment: Did you restart VS? If so, delete the `.vs` folder, and restart again. VS does get drunk at times.

Comment: This might be related to another bug with the Tool Windows.  Click inside the errors window so it gains focus and press **Ctrl+Break** a few times.  It might work.  It was the fix strangely when **Find in Files** stopped working

Comment: I tried restarting. Repairing the installation, rebooting and deleting the .vs folder. After repairing no errors show in the Errors window - even when I build.

Answer (score 0):

Well...I tried a whole bunch of solutions. None of them worked. I uninstalled and reinstalled VS. That did not work. I started running into an error whenre a file could not install because of a account issue.

it turns out after a bunch of tech support from Microsoft Installation help that I had to reinstall Windows :(. The bottom line is that my accounts became messed up. I reset the password to the admin account on my computer. After that I couldn't log in to my account.

Well...sometimes it's just good to start over.

By the way, I had everything backed up using Unitrends on a virtual machine. I love that stuff. Even let me restore on a file level only to my new computer.

All is well now.